# User Has No Claims With Windows Authentication in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .Net Core 3.1 app running on IIS that uses Windows authentication via client certificates.  On my local IIS, everything works as it should and the user's claims are correctly set up, however once I deploy it to our remote test site using IIS, the user no longer receives any claims.  On both environments, I have Anonymous Authentication disabled and Windows Authentication enabled within IIS.  On the test environment, it allows me to access the site, so I know it's authenticating through IIS, but it seems like for whatever reason, the user's claims aren't getting set by .Net Core.  I have combed through I don't know how many SO threads and also a bunch of GitHub issues (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18040) and haven't been able to figure out why this is happening.  Below is the code in my Startup.cs file.  Appreciate any help as to why this isn't working on our test server.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("SearchSettings").Bind(options));
        services.AddSingleton<IndexCache>();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you got any error messages? such as in the event viewer.

Comment: No errors in event log.  Also enabled the stdout log and get nothing there either.  The IIS log successfully shows my user account in the request, but for whatever reason, it's not being passed to the application as User.Claims and User.Identity are empty.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.